# change password in nodejs, mongoDB with passport

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passwords, passport.js, passport-local

I'm using JWT with Passport for authentication in my app, but I don't know how to change the password.

This is my login function:

```
function login(req, res, next) {
    const userObj = {
        email: req.body.email,
        userType: req.body.userType
    };
    UserSchema.findOneAsync(userObj, '+password')
        .then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
            const err = new APIError('User not found with the given email id', httpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            return next(err);
        } else {
            user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (passwordError, isMatch) => {
            if (passwordError || !isMatch) {
                const err = new APIError('Incorrect password', httpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                return next(err);
            }
            user.loginStatus = true;
            user.gpsLoc = [19.02172902354515, 72.85368273308545];
            const token = jwt.sign(user, config.jwtSecret);
            UserSchema.findOneAndUpdateAsync({ _id: user._id }, { $set: user }, { new: true })
                .then((updatedUser) => {
                const returnObj = {
                    success: true,
                    message: 'user successfully logged in',
                    data: {
                    jwtAccessToken: `JWT ${token}`,
                    user: updatedUser
                    }
                };
                res.json(returnObj);
                })
                .error((err123) => {
                const err = new APIError(`error in updating user details while login ${err123}`, httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                next(err);
                });
            });
        }
    })
    .error((e) => {
        const err = new APIError(`erro while finding user ${e}`, httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        next(err);
    });
}
```

my user DB is like this.

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import httpStatus from 'http-status';
import APIError from '../helpers/APIError';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fname: { type: String, default: null },
    lname: { type: String, default: null },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function userSchemaPre(next) {
    const user = this;
    if (this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (hashErr, hash) => {
            if (hashErr) {
            return next(hashErr);
            }
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
        });
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function comparePassword(pw, cb) {
    const that = this;
    bcrypt.compare(pw, that.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (err) {
        return cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};
```

I have made another function for reset password and matching checked old password is valid like login function, now I want to update new passport in DB. how will I do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking for here, but a changePassword function is just a simple update on UserSchema. Here is a sample:

```
function changePassword(req, res, next) {


// Init Variables
  var passwordDetails = req.body;

  if (req.user) {
    if (passwordDetails.newPassword) {
      UserSchema.findById(req.user.id, function (err, user) {
        if (!err && user) {
          if (user.authenticate(passwordDetails.currentPassword)) {
            if (passwordDetails.newPassword === passwordDetails.verifyPassword) {
              user.password = passwordDetails.newPassword;

              user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                  return res.status(422).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                  });
                } else {
                  req.login(user, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                      res.status(400).send(err);
                    } else {
                      res.send({
                        message: 'Password changed successfully'
                      });
                    }
                  });
                }
              });
            } else {
              res.status(422).send({
                message: 'Passwords do not match'
              });
            }
          } else {
            res.status(422).send({
              message: 'Current password is incorrect'
            });
          }
        } else {
          res.status(400).send({
            message: 'User is not found'
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.status(422).send({
        message: 'Please provide a new password'
      });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({
      message: 'User is not signed in'
    });
  }
};
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to write any methods in schema. You can directly use ChangePassword function with schema like this

```
 user.changePassword(req.body.oldpassword, req.body.newpassword, function(err) 
   {
```